# Categorical GROUP BY with Monthly Totals

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like below with the employee name, Position, Hire Date and Exit Date.

```
+----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| Employee |    Position    | Hire Date | Exit Date |
+----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| John     | Manager        | 1-Feb-18  |           |
| Mike     | Senior Manager | 12-Oct-18 | 20-Jul-22 |
| Jennifer | Manager        | 3-Apr-19  |           |
| Cindy    | CSR            | 25-Nov-19 | 30-Mar-22 |
| Tom      | CSR            | 18-Jul-22 |           |
| Rodrigo  | Director       | 19-Oct-21 |           |
| Ashley   | CSR            | 17-Jan-22 |           |
+----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am looking to get the monthly headcount totals for each position starting January 2020.  If Exit Date is blank it means that the employee is still currently working at the company. Below is an example of the desired output I am looking for:

```
+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----+--------+
|    Position    | Jan-20 | Feb-20 | Mar-20 | Apr-20 | …. | Sep-22 |
+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----+--------+
| Manager        |      5 |      6 |      7 |      4 |    |      9 |
| Senior Manager |      2 |      1 |      4 |      4 |    |      4 |
| Director       |      1 |      1 |      2 |      3 |    |      5 |
| CSR            |     10 |     14 |     15 |     15 |    |     18 |
+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----+--------+
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please specify the dbms you are using for accurate anwsers, but for short you may need to read something about PIVOT in SQL.

Comment: I will actually be using the pandasql package in python